# Error while posting json data

Tags: android, json, http-headers

I am trying to post json object

```
{"venue":"places, US"}
```

using below code-

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 30000);
HttpResponse response;
try {
     HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
     StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());
     se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
     post.setEntity(se);
     post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
     post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
     response = client.execute(post);

} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Client", "sendJson", e);
}
```

However I am getting below error response from server-

```
{"description":"Invalid token character ',' in token \"json, application/json\"","errorCode":2000}
```

What is reason for that error from from server. Is is because of some header setting on server side or there is some problem with request code I pasted above.

**Edit:**
Looks like this error is due to content type setting 2 times. After removing below line

```
se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
```

error is gone.

But when I only remove below line instead of line written above, it does not remove error.

```
post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
```

Why removing only first line works and when I remove 2nd one error is still there as both are setting content type.

Also I have used that code with both lines in it in other projects and it worked in them without any error. It looks like server side issue, what setting on server may have caused this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing the

```
post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
```

line. It looks like you'r adding the content-type header twice and the server has some problems with that.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Removing post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json"); didnt work. But when I removed this line se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")); it worked and I got expected response from server. What can be reason for it? Again thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you're setting the `Content-Type` header twice.  Once with the string literal at the end, and once at the beginning with the `HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE`.

The way I solved this in my project was by extending `StringEntity` to behave exactly the same, except for setting its `Content-Type` to `application/json`.  That way, I never had to think about it again.

Comment: Thanks for replying. when I removed the line se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")); I got no error from server. Thanks for helping.